# Serialize netty's FullHttpRequest

Tags: netty

I have a netty server running in my Java project, and is listening to requests. Netty internally converts the request to `FullHttpRequest` type before giving it to the handler. Now in my handler, I am trying to serialize [FullHttpRequest](https://zgrepcode.com/netty/4.1/io/netty/handler/codec/http/fullhttprequest.java) because I have to push it to RabbtitMQ. But looks like that it is is not serializable:

```
due java.io.NotSerializableException: io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpRequest
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.createTypeConversionException(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:566)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpRequest
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:139)
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:161)
    at com.company.myproject.util.RequestToByteArrayConverter.convertTo(RequestToByteArrayConverter.java:28)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:276)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:165)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways one can address this.

- Extend FullHttpRequest/Response to implement Serializable. It's just hectic as you might end up writing read/write resolves for quite a number of classes.
- Create your own shadow classes of FullHttpRequest/Response which copy meaningful bits from shadowed classes and are serializable. Then write your own adapters

I personally went with shadow approach.

Comment: I already ended up doing what you have suggested in point 2. Anyway thanks :)